# Magento 2 DevBox Use with Window10

Tags: magento2, m2devbox

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/docker/docker-over.html

I am using devbox into window 10, and it is working fine, but one question, how to share code between virtual machine and window.

So easily manage code between virtual machine and my code, by using that way i want to speed my development into window.

Answer (score 0):

You can run devbox-unison-sync script in package that you downloaded. In windows sync mode not fast so you need unison for that. Recommended you move to linux if you can

With devbox mode:
Modify file devbox-unison-sync.bat

```
@SET LOCAL_ROOT=./shared/webroot/app
@SET REMOTE_ROOT=socket://localhost:%UNISON_PORT%//var/www/magento2/app
```

Comment: already tried but in that way i can share whole magento 2 not able to share only app folder.

Comment: You can change params for local and container root for sync. See updated in my answer